# In Mongo, map over array and update docs

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update multiple docs in mongo.

I have an array, and I want to update multiple mongo docs with a specific object from that array.

```
let items = [{ order: 0 }, { order: 1 }, { order: 2 }]
```

I have tried this for updating mongo:

```
items.map((item) => {
    db.items.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: item._id },
        { $set: { order: item.order } }
    )
})
```

If I check items, it has actually updated the array:

```
console.log(items)
```

But when I look in my database, MongoDB has not updated.

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is a synchronous function and you are using it to for an asynchronous update with `findOneAndUpdate`, akin to mixing water and oil.

You either need to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) or [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) with the map function. For example, with the above, you can create an array of promises with the map function and resolve with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
const updatePromises = items.map(({ _id, order }) => (
    Item.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, {'$set': { order } })
)) 

Promise.all(updatePromises).then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

Using async/await

```
(async () => {
    try {
        for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
            await Item.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: item._id },
                { $set: { order: item.order } }
            )
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
})()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! Unfortunately neither worked, it still is not saving to mongodb.

Comment: What's your model name in Mongoose?

Comment: const itemSchema = new Schema({ order: Number })  const Item = mongoose.model('item', itemSchema);  then later I'm calling Item.findOneAndUpdate(...

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that I was already using my model name (and it still didn't work)

Comment: nvm, got it! small typo. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!